# Import many files using loop

Tags: r

I have several in CSV format and I need to import them and transform them into DF using “FOR”. Name of my files:

FILE1.CSV; FILE2.CSV; FILE3.CSV

```
#FILE1
NAME<- c("JOHN","DONALD","CARL")
PRICE <- c(50, 60, 70)
FILE1 <- data.frame(NAME,PRICE)

#FILE2
NAME<- c("MICHAEL","CRIS","MARY")
PRICE <- c(12, 33, 78)
CITY<- c("NY", "LA","LON")
FILE2 <- data.frame(NAME,PRICE,CITY)

#FILE3
NAME<- c("PAUL","BROWN","WAL")
PRICE <- c(99, 54, 22)
CITY<- c("PAR","RIO","LIS")
POP<- c(150,369,871)
FILE3 <- data.frame(NAME,PRICE,CITY,POP)
```

Before turning them into DF I want to treat each file. Suppose that the import, treatment and transformation in DF has this sequence:

```
#PART 1
require(tidyverse)
setwd("D:/")

#PART 2
list_file <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>% lapply(read.csv, sep=";")
```

I have an error here, because only the first file (FILE1) is transformed into DF and the rest are not transformed. I don't know how to fix it.

```
# PART 3
for (i in 1:seq_along(list_file)){
  DF<- as_tibble(list_file[[i]]) %>% select(NAME,PRICE) # Only the variables “NAME” and “PRICE” will be used.
}
```

From here I want to import `FILE2`, treat it and add it to the existing DF (rbind). And so on until my last file `(FILE3)`. Therefore, as I would do to: 1) import; 2) handle the file and 3) add to a `DF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop, we need to store it in a `list` as 'DF' is getting updated in each iteration

```
lst1 <- vector('list', length(list_file))
for (i in seq_along(list_file)){
  lst1[[i]] <- as_tibble(list_file[[i]]) %>% 
         select(NAME,PRICE) 
  }
```

From the `list`, we can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` to bind them `rbind` won't work if the column names are not matching or have extra columns in one of the `list` element and not in the other

```
bind_rows(lst1)
```

---

Also, as we are using tidyverse functions

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
out <- map_dfr(list.files(pattern = "*\\.csv"), ~
          read_csv(.x) %>%
             select(NAME, PRICE)
 )
```

---

Or if we use `fread`, there is an option to `select` the columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern = "*\\.csv"), fread,
         select = c("NAME", "PRICE")))
```

Comment: Thanks! When I used your suggestion for "lst1" ... the following message comes: "Warning message: "In 1: seq_along (list_file): numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used"

Comment: @BrunoAvila  Sorry, it is the same code you used.  it should be `for(i in seq_along(list_file))` and not `1:seq_along`

Comment: @BrunoAvila  I didn't notice it earlier.  You would get the same warning with `1:seq_along(1:3)#
[1] 1
Warning message:
In 1:seq_along(1:3) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used`.  Instead, it would be just `seq_along`